# Desktop Sharing crashes Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I open up the settings dialog on my Ubuntu system and select Desktop Sharing.  The program seems to start, but soon the screen goes gray and issues an error report.  I sent that in for review.  I have looked at messages others have posted which say to select Ubuntu Xorg.  That appeared to be in the crash log details.  Is there a work around for this error?

Comment: When you login, you can select X,org or Wayland to manage the display; see https://ubuntu.com/blog/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default  and https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: I used the second recommended method to modify the custom.conf file.  Unfortunately, the line for disabling Wayland was already commented out.  Desktop Sharing still crashes.  The detailed explanation tells me I have a number of apps which need updating.  Unfortunately, the camera capture board I am using relies on older components.  This is not an option.